# gsub not working throughout code snippet

Tags: ruby, gsub

Using this code example

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
paragraph = "champion xylophone excellent"
paragraph = paragraph.gsub("ch","tj")
words = paragraph.split(/ /)
words.each do |word|
   if word[0,1] == "x"
     word[0.1] = "z" 
   end
end
paragraph = words.join(" ")
paragraph.gsub("x","ks")
print paragraph
```

The output will be 'tjampion zylophone excellent' rather than 'tjampion zylophone ekscellent'

The same applies if the gsub is applied within the each to the individual words. I don't understand why it acts at the beginning but not at the end.

**Edit**

Second case is a distinct issue from the first:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
paragraph = "champion xylophone excellent"
paragraph = paragraph.gsub("ch","tj")
words = paragraph.split(/ /)
words.each do |word|
   if word[0,1] == "x"
     word[0.1] = "z" 
   end
   word = word.gsub("x","ks")
end
paragraph = words.join(" ")
print paragraph
```

Comment: See below I updated. One line of code can do all operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you first use gsub you are assigning it to paragrah

```
paragraph = paragraph.gsub("ch","tj")
```

The second time you are missing the assignment

change `paragraph.gsub("x","ks")` to

```
paragraph = paragraph.gsub("x","ks")
```

Comment: or change to 'paragraph.gsub!("x","ks")'

Comment: What a plonker, you are right! Any thoughts about the second case as that seems to be different altogether?

Answer (score 2):

```
paragraph.gsub!("x","ks")
puts paragraph
```

Or use RegExp (one line operation can do all):

```
paragraph = "champion xylophone excellent"
paragraph = paragraph.gsub("ch","tj").gsub(/([\A\s])x(\w*)/){$1 + 'z'+ $2}.gsub("x","ks")

puts paragraph
```

Comment: does using the assignment operator create a new 'word' element in my code ?

Comment: No. `obj.each` only pass the "VALUE" of the reference (rather than pass by reference; a bit confusing and worth a bit digging deep). For example, `[1,2].each { |x| x += 1}` will still give `[1,2]`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working by accident. The working parts use methods on strings that modify the string; the not working parts use methods that produce a new string (which is discarded). This is confusing; a better way would be to use `map` if the desired result is an array. It would contain the results of the block, either modified strings or new ones.

```
paragraph = "champion xylophone excellent"
words = paragraph.split(' ').map do |word|
  word.gsub('ch','tj') #new string
  word[0.1] = "z" if word.start_with?('x') #modified string
  word.gsub!('x','ks') #modified string
end
puts words.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `gsub` to be destructive, i.e. to change the value of the variable on which it was called, use `gsub!`. so:

```
paragraph.gsub!('ch', 'tj')
```

rather than:

```
paragraph = paragraph.gsub('ch', 'tj')
```

It's more concise, and Ruby developers recognize bang (!) methods as destructive.  And in your case, you need the `gsub!` method in place of both calls to `gsub`

Comment: there is a typo in the second example, not sure if it causes the problem though: `word[0.1] = "z"` shouldn't the . be a ,?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the issue, fixing it results in the same output